# Sitecore with SOLR: An index with the name "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master" have already been added

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I get this error when configuring SOLR 6.3 with Sitecore 8.1. I have done all steps from the following post, but after complete steps I get the following error:

An index with the name "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master" have already been added.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An index with the name "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master" have already been added.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: An index with the name "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master" have already been added.]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String message) +81
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration.AddIndex(ISearchIndex index) +185

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +869
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +655
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +322
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +619
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +262
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_Cores() +92
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp.Initialize() +255
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +259
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +704
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712

Comment: Can you check all your config files for "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master"? Seems like that index definition might be there twice.

Answer (score 0):

You might still have *.Lucene.* configs in your App_Config/Include folder that have not yet been disabled. Need to add .disabled to all Lucene config files.